# Is AWS Aurora for PostgreSQL not available in ca-central-1 region?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to set up an Aurora PostgreSQL database in ca-central-1 (Canada) through Amazon's web interface, but the dashboard only gives me the option of picking Aurora MySQL.

Are Aurora PostgreSQL-compatible instances not available in Canada yet, or is this a bug in Amazon's web interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Aurora Postgres SQL Compatible instances are not available in Canada yet. You can refer the [pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/pricing/) to find out the availability for respective database engines.